# Is Lipschitz $f(t,x)=x^{2/3} \sin(1/x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I'm having a little trouble trying to prove it.
I have to study existence and unicity of next Cauchy's problem:
$$x'=f(t,x), x(t_0)=x_0,$$
where $$f(t,x)=x^{2/3}\sin(1/x), (t,x)\neq(t,0)$$ and $$f(t,0)=0,$$
It's clearly that $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Also, I can't say anything about existence and unicity when $x_0=0$ because $f$ is not Lipschitz, so I can't apply Picard:
$$\frac{|f(t,x)-f(t,0)|}{|x-0|}  =\frac{|\sin(1/x)|}{|x|}\rightarrow\infty, x\rightarrow0.$$
My teacher have said that $f$ is Lipschitz (global!) in every neighbourhood of $(t_0,x_0)$ if $x_0\neq0$. I don't know how to do it. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a $t$ missing somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean $f(0,x)$ in place of $f(t,x)$? The term you are looking for at the end is "neighbourhood".

Comment: No, Lipschitz respect variable x. I got $x^{2/3}sin(1/x)-y^{2/3}sin(1/y)$. Litle strange to reduce it.

Comment: But your $f(t,x)$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: Yes, but I don't why it cares. For example, $f(x)=x$ is Lipschitz , but is not $f(x)=x^2$. If I define $f(t, x)=x$ it will be also Lipschitz. It's the way we defined Cauchy's  problem: $x'=f(t,x)$.